# MeanShift in Matlab with custom kernel

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis, matlab, pattern-recognition

Is there an implementation of MeanShift, written in Matlab, which allows to use a custom Kernel?

Comment: It may not be too hard to adapt the file exchange entry: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10161-mean-shift-clustering

Comment: First give it a try and if you get stuck at any specific point we can try to help.

Comment: I suppose I just have to modify the type of distance evaluated to find points inside the Parzen windows, defined by bandwidth parameter...